# Java8 has completely removed permgen space from it's memory area. will it completely stop memory leak issues ? ...

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, java-8, permgen

This is what I have got from oracle site:

**Area: HotSpot / gc**

**Synopsis**

```
The command line flags PermSize and MaxPermSize have been removed and are 
ignored. If used on the command line a warning will be emitted for each.

Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=32m; support 
was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m;
support was removed in 8.0
```

**Nature of Incompatibility**

```
source
```

Comment: The removal of the permgen space can’t stop memory leaks as the former existence of the permgen space never was the cause of memory leaks.

Comment: It is really bad if someone without understanding the question or the context of asking my question just simply down vote it !!! . Regarding this question whoever has downvoted it either he/she doesn't understand java or it was simply a revenge . Have never done this kind of thing to anyone unless there is enough reason to do so .

Comment: @Holger : 
I never said existence of permgen space caused memory leaks. permgen space in jvm meant for storing the metadata of the objects that our application is using. If there is any unused object which GC fails to remove then it becomes a memory leak there by producing some outofmemory error . 
https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/permgen-memory-leak/

Comment: Then, your entire question is illogical. If you understood that permgen is not the cause of memory leaks, why did you ask whether its removal will stop memory leak issues? You can never solve any issue without removing the cause.

Comment: God help us if the internal memory management of the gc has memory issues!! I would suspect this has been thoroughly tested and the most likely location of leaks might be in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Of course memory leaks are still possible. Actually most of memory leaks appear in normal heap, not in permgen/metaspace, so this change don't affect them. For example, one may create a `HashMap` in static field and gradually fill it without removing elements. This way heap consumption will constantly grow.

Also moving class data from permgen to metaspace doesn't mean that it does not require space. It's just allocated in off-heap region and can be controlled via `MaxMetaspaceSize` option (infinity by default). This change is mostly internal (makes some things in JVM easier) and does not affect normal programmers. The only visible problem it solves is that with default setting you will now unlikely to have problems when too many classes are loaded. But this will not help you if you have a significant class loader leak: you are still limited by physical memory and swap size on your machine.